# Change strings in multiple files to current subdirectory name

Tags: files, rename

I have several directories each containing a file containing this line:

```
../a_a_q1.out ../a_a_q2.out ../a_a_q3.out
```

I would like to loop through all the subdirectories, and change the `a_a` part to the current subdirectory name. For example, if a subdirectory is called `awesome_directory`, I would like this line to read:

```
../awesome_directory_q1.out ../awesome_directory_q2.out ../awesome_directory_q3.out
```

How would I achieve this?

I would just like to use the subdirectory name. For example, I would just need the (`awesome_directory`) part instead of the full deal (`//something/server/user/other_stuff/more/awesome_directory`)

Answer (score 1):

In two steps in bash here is a way -

```
epwd=$(basename `pwd`)
sed -i "s/a_a/$epwd/g" <filename>
```

The variable `$epwd` contains an escaped directory name, that can be taken to sed.
And the sed command substitutes all occurrences of a_a by the working directory

EDITED : The first line of the original answer has been edited to just have the current directory name and not the full path. If you want the full path use

```
epwd=$(pwd|sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

Comment: I'm getting an error after running the second command that says:
syntax error near expected token 'newline'

Comment: @Melanie - that's because the `<` and `>` are not actually supposed to be used, I guess.

Comment: @MelanieShebel ,  have edited my answer for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```sh
set '%s_q1.out %s_q2.out %s_q3.out\n'
:|for d in several directories
do      cd  -P -- "$d" || ! break
        set "$1" "../${PWD##*/}"
        {   sed -ne'\|\( \.\./a_a_q[123]\.out\)\{3\}|q;s/.//p'
            printf "$@" "$2" "$2";  cut -c2-
        } <<-IN >./infile
        $(paste -d\  - ./infile)
        IN
done
```

That should work with a POSIX `sed` and a `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `mksh` shell and many others. With a `dash` or `yash` shell the here-document will not likely be backed with a regular file and so you cannot rely on the `lseek()` function required to support sharing the input. In those cases you should switch to one of the aforementioned shells.

If you use a GNU `sed` you'll want to use `sed -une` as opposed to just `sed -ne`.

Here's a breakdown:

1. First we `set` an arg we'll be using as `printf`'s format string over and over and set both `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD` to `.`
2. Next we start iterating over items in *`several directories`*. Whether these are actual directories or symlinks we get the `-P`hysical, canonical pathname in `$PWD` and `set` it's last path-component to `$2`.
3. The next thing that happens occurs at the bottom in the heredoc redirection. `paste` reads all of `./infile` out to some secure temporary file the shell has secured for us while prepending a single space to every line. The shell then sets that temporary file to stdin and `./infile` is once again assigned - but this time as stdout.
4. `sed` does very little editing. Until it encounters your match line it strips the first character from every line and `p`rints the results. Once it encounters your line it `q`uits input entirely - printing nothing.
5. But `printf` prints `../${PWD##*/}_q[123].out` followed by a newline to stdout, and afterward `cut` picks up stdin where `sed` left it *(just after your match line)* and reads the rest out while stripping the first byte from every input line.

And so the whole of the edited `./infile` winds up right back where it came from in one piece.

Oh, I did test it.

I replaced the *`several directories`* bit with the pathname `/tmp` and did...

```sh
{   seq 7
    echo '../a_a_q1.out ../a_a_q2.out ../a_a_q3.out'
    seq 9 14
    printf %s\\n '' '' ''
}  >/tmp/infile
```

...which wrote out a *`/tmp/infile`* which looked like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
../a_a_q1.out ../a_a_q2.out ../a_a_q3.out
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

After running the code snippet above on `/tmp`, though...

```sh
cat /tmp/infile
```

---

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
../tmp_q1.out ../tmp_q2.out ../tmp_q3.out
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this so far.

```
var=("${PWD##*/}")

sed -i "s/a_a/$var/g" filename
```

Comment: It's ok if `a_a` only ever occurs on the one line and if your directory names are sane. The problem with this and another answer here though is what happens when your dirnames are *not*. If you have `sed` meta chars in the dirnames - *(like `&` in this case, or backslashes, or newlines)* weird results can occur. You can handle it like `var=$(printf "%s \n" "${PWD##*/}" | sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/[]\/$*.^&[]/\\&/g;s/\n/\\&/g');var=${var%?}`. Pretty much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
cd /something/server/user/other_stuff/more &&
  zmv -n '(*)/a_a(_*)' '$1/$1$2'
```

Remove `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

Or from `/something/server/user` looking recursively for `a_a_*` files:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)/a_a(_*)' '$1$2/$2$3'
```

(note that it doesn't look into hidden dirs, add a `(#qD)` to the end of the pattern for them to be included).

Answer (score 1):

If the `a_a` part is constant and you're running Linux, then you can use the `rename` utility. On Debian and derivatives, change `rename` to `rename.ul` as the `rename` command is a different utility which can also do this job but has a different syntax.

Iterate over the directories with a loop:

```
for d in */; do … done
```

Call `rename` to rename the files in each directory.

```
for d in */; do
  rename /a_a "/${d%/}" "$d"a_a*
done
```